# Observing events for elements with a certain class or that element's children using event delegation

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, event-delegation

I have a page with elements similar to this:

```
<div id='things'>
    <div class='thing'>
        <div class='activator'>
            <span>Some text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is similar to this:

```
$('things').observe(click, function(event) {
    var e = event.element();
    if (e.match('.activator')) {
        doSomeStuffWith(e);
    } else if (e.match('.activator *')) {
        doSomeStuffWith(e.up('.activator');
    }
});
```

So if I click the .activator or any of its child elements I want to call a function on the .activator, I'm just wondering if there isn't some way of combining the two if-clauses. Something like if (e.match('.class, .class *') { doStuff(e.upOrSelf('activator')); }

I guess I could extend the Element with an upOrSelf method. But I would prefer not to do any non-standard customizations if possible.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/435-eventdelegate-and-elementmethodsdelegate) for discussions about a more generic way to to event delegation in Prototype. Down the page there is an [implementation](http://s3.amazonaws.com/activereload-lighthouse/assets/123564375a9cdf6e1065c7119841ff0e81215c8e/delegate.js?AWSAccessKeyId=1AJ9W2TX1B2Z7C2KYB82&Expires=1251978459&Signature=5U6PMn9mz8It80uanNkitZlTpsI%3D) of `Event.delegate()` which uses a little trick to achieve what you want. It gathers the target element and its ancestors and applies the event listener to all matching elements using `Selector.matchElements`.

It's a bit more complicated than this, but here is an abbreviated version (untested):

```
$('things').observe('click', function(event) {
    var child = event.element();
    var ancestors = [child].concat(child.ancestors());
    Selector.matchElements(ancestors, '.activator').each(function(element) {
       doSomeStuffWith(element);
    });
})
```